How to make a dictionary of string keys and Celery task as value using MyPy types?
I got the following code:
CeleryTask: TypeAlias = "Task[Any, Any]"

@celery.task(
  bind=True,
  ...
)
def handle_webhook(self: CeleryTask, webhook: Webhook) -> None:
  # do stuff

Then I have a dictionary like this:
webhook_map: dict[str, Callable[[Task, 'Webhook'], None]] = {
  "order.webhook": handle_webhook
}

I also tried different ways, like this:
webhook_map: dict[str, (CeleryTask, Webhook)] = {
  "order.webhook": handle_webhook
}

webhook_map: dict[str, CeleryTask] = {
  "order.webhook": handle_webhook
}

But none of this works. When I later fetch the value from the dict, MyPy is complaining that delay method does not exist on the task.
How can I properly save the CeleryTasks in my dict and call delay to schedule them later? Is this possible in Python? Thanks!
